# chipmunk collision too soft

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, physics, chipmunk, cocos2d-x

I'm new to physics in cocos2d. I'm using chipmunk, and when two object collide, its just to "soft", like they where made of sponge or rubber.

My code:

```
cpInitChipmunk();  
space = cpSpaceNew();  
space->gravity = cpv(0, 0);  
schedule(schedule_selector(HelloWorld::step), 1.0f/60.f);
astroBody = cpBodyNew(100, INFINITY);  
astroBody->p = cpv(512,384);
cpSpaceAddBody(space, astroBody);
int num2 = 8;
cpVect vertsAstro[] =  {
    cpv(-17.0f, -44.9f),
    cpv(-29.5f, -33.2f),
    cpv(-32.9f, -13.1f),
    cpv(-24.0f, 11.7f),
    cpv(24.6f, 11.5f),
    cpv(32.9f, -12.9f),
    cpv(29.3f, -33.1f),
    cpv(17.0f, -44.7f)
};
astroShape = cpPolyShapeNew(astroBody, num2, vertsAstro, cpv(0,0));
astroShape->e = 0.0f;
astroShape->u = 0.0f;
astroShape->collision_type = 0; 
astroShape->data = player;
cpSpaceAddShape(space, astroShape);

cpBody *box = cpBodyNew(INFINITY, INFINITY);  
box->p = cpv(z->getPosition().x+32, z->getPosition().y+32); 
int num = 5;
cpVect verts[] = {
    cpv(-32, -32),
    cpv(-32, 32),
    cpv(32, 32),
    cpv(32, -32),
    cpv(-32, -32)
};
cpShape *boxShape = cpPolyShapeNew(box, num, verts, cpv(0,0));
boxShape->e = 0.0f;
boxShape->u = 0.0f;
boxShape->collision_type = 1;  
boxShape->data = z;
cpSpaceAddStaticShape(space, boxShape);
```

So these objects are colliding, and it is too soft. Can I make it somehow to look like two stones hit each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be using Chipmunk 5. You need to set the fields directly such as shape->e = 1.0.

The getter/setter functions are part of Chipmunk 6. You can still set the fields directly, but it's recommended not to as the setter functions will automatically wake up objects when changing values.

Comment: I collide the player and objects by setting the velocity of the player ( `astroBody->v = vector;` ) This is made every tick. I think this could be the problem.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I use now cpBodyApplyForce(), and now it works perfectly. The object collide now hard, just as i wanted. Setting the velocity directly was too much.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

`void cpShapeSetElasticity(cpShape *shape, cpFloat value)`

> Elasticity of the shape. A value of 0.0 gives no bounce, while a value
>   of 1.0 will give a “perfect” bounce. However due to inaccuracies in
>   the simulation using 1.0 or greater is not recommended however. The
>   elasticity for a collision is found by multiplying the elasticity of
>   the individual shapes together.

Does this help?

Comment: I think it's deprecated, or something: `'cpShapeSetElasticity': identifier not found`