# Dynamic Body can get into a Static Body (chipmunk physics)

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

i meet a trouble with chipmunk physic. I have a tank and a box here my code example:
code fox Box:

```
auto edgeSp = Sprite::create();
auto boundBody = PhysicsBody::createBox(Size(100, 100));
boundBody->setContactTestBitmask(0x1);
boundBody->setDynamic(false);
edgeSp->setPhysicsBody(boundBody);
```

code for Tank:

```
Sprite* tank=Sprite::create(“tank.png”);
auto physicbody = PhysicsBody::createBox(this->getContentSize());
physicbody->setContactTestBitmask(0x1);
tank->setPhysicsBody(physicbody);
```

and my trouble is when i set setvelocity for tank,tank can get into the Box then pushed out. How i can prevent that?

[Image Tank can get into Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlMNC.png)

[And pushed out after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v5zx.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [chipmunk collision too soft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452777/chipmunk-collision-too-soft)

Comment: kabanus thank you, i come see that ^^